# "for the sake of" | synonyms

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Are there any other ways of writing the following while keeping the same meaning?

> for the sake of

I have used it so much in my essay, so I am searching a thing which gives the same meaning.

Comment: There's insufficient context in your question to enable others to give good answers. How about an example or two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest "In the interest of" or "On account of"

Both mean "Because of" which is what "For the sake of" means

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> for the purpose of/ For the purpose of clarification, let's....
>   In view of/ In view of the defendant...

Comment: I like "in view of"

Answer (score 0):

I generally use "for the purposes of". 
But depending on context:
"with regard to/regarding/as regards"
"in view of"
would work. 
I personally would not use "for the sake of" in academic writings.

Comment: Google Scholar estimates [1.1 million examples of *for the sake of*"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22for+the+sake+of%22) in its corpus. Can you provide a more detailed explanation as to why you believe it is unsuitable, and why the others are suitable? I would also encourage you to review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help)'s guidance on [how to write good answers](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).